# ResultSet closed (prior to insert into)

Tags: java

Have an issue with a closed ResultSet prior to a SQL insert (Java / Netbeans)

```
Connection var2 = DBConnPool.getInstance().getConnection();
Statement var3 = null;
String var5;
ResultSet var8 = null;

try {
    var3 = var2.createStatement();

    var5 = "insert into triggers (ts, nodeip, trapname) values (now(), '"+ipaddress+"', '"+trapname+"')";
    var3.execute(var5);

    var5 = "select asset.id as assetid, node.id as nodeid \n" +
        "from asset, node\n" +
        "where asset.name LIKE 'Trigger%'\n" +
        "and node.ipaddress=\'"+ipaddress+"'";
    var8 = var3.executeQuery(var5);

    while(var8.next()){
        int var31 = var8.getInt("assetid");
        int var32 = var8.getInt("nodeid");

        var5 = "insert into alerts (ts, assetid, alerttypeid, nodeid, ack) values (now(), " + var31 + ", 15, " + var32 + ", 0)";
        var3.execute(var5);
        var5 ="insert into logs (ts, rssi, nodeid, assetid) values (now(), 1000, " + var32 + ", " + var31 + ")";
        var3.execute(var5);
    }
}
```

The select asset.id query seems to be running ok, but at the point of

```
while(var8.next()) {
    int var31 = var8.getInt("assetid");
    int var32 = var8.getInt("nodeid");
```

Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed.

Do I have to do the inserts outside of the  while(var8.next())  and, if so, how do I recover / refer to the variables var31 and var32?

Apologies, I know the var names are not very helpful, but the insert commands should be straightforward (or so I thought)

Thoughts appreciated

Regards
Active

Comment: Exactly what line gives you "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"?

Comment: while(var8.next())

Comment: Not sure, but you may need to create a new statement after the first is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to separate the responsability for every statement:**

```
Connection var2 = DBConnPool.getInstance().getConnection();
Statement var3 = null;
Statement stmQuery = null;
String var5;
ResultSet var8 = null;

try {
    var3 = var2.createStatement();
    stmQuery = var2.createStatement();

    var5 = "insert into triggers (ts, nodeip, trapname) values (now(), '"+ipaddress+"', '"+trapname+"')";
    var3.execute(var5);

    var5 = "select asset.id as assetid, node.id as nodeid \n" +
        "from asset, node\n" +
        "where asset.name LIKE 'Trigger%'\n" +
        "and node.ipaddress=\'"+ipaddress+"'";
    var8 = stmQuery.executeQuery(var5);

    while(var8.next()){
        int var31 = var8.getInt("assetid");
        int var32 = var8.getInt("nodeid");

        var5 = "insert into alerts (ts, assetid, alerttypeid, nodeid, ack) values (now(), " + var31 + ", 15, " + var32 + ", 0)";
        var3.execute(var5);
        var5 ="insert into logs (ts, rssi, nodeid, assetid) values (now(), 1000, " + var32 + ", " + var31 + ")";
        var3.execute(var5);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    //Somthing went wrong!
} finally {
    var3.close();
    stmQuery.close();
    var8.close();
    var2.close();
}
```

***TIP:*** As you can see, it's very important to close resources within finally block.

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Thanks Eleazar, much appreciated. The Try block is working, something not quite right with finally but I will work on that.